# How to use find() in MATLAB in order to find decimals

Tags: matlab, find

I am given a table with two columns - one is P_in and the other P_out:

```
P_in  = table(:,1);
P_out = table(:,2);
```

I am also given a subset of P_in, which I call P_in2. I want to find the corresponding value of P_out that belongs to P_in2.

I tried find():

```
P_out2_idx = find(table(P_in2,2));
P_out2     = table(P_out2,idx,2);
```

But find() can only deal with integers. My table however, does not show integers, but decimals. Here are three lines from the table:

```
-13.02    49.6
-12.52    49.9
-12.02    50.18
```

So even rounding the P_in2 values wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you show us how `P_in2` is defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ismember` is good for finding multiple indices if your numbers are integers. For floating-point numbers a safer way is using [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html):

```
isInP_in2 = ismembertol(P_in, P_in2, eps);
P_out2 = P_out(isInP_in2);
```

The returned array `isInP_in2` is a logical array the size of `P_in`, which is `true` at the indices where values in `P_in2` are found, and `false` otherwise.

The third argument is the tolerance used for comparisons (here we take the floating-point relative accuracy [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)). For example, searching for a single index using `find` would be done:

```
idx = find(abs(P_in - P_in2(1)) < eps);
```

Comment: would it be possible to say: isInP_in2 = ismembertol(P_in -3,P_in2,eps); ? In order to find all the values of P_in2 which are in P_in - 3 ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Just to be clear: say you have `P_in=[1 2 3]`, and `P_in2=[-2 -4]`, you want to find the indices `[1 3]`?

Comment: When P_in=[1 2 3] and P_in2=[-2 -4], I want to find index 1, because P_in(1)-3 = -2.  If P_in=[1 2 3] and P_in2 =[-2 1 0], I want to find indices 1 and 3, because P_in(1)-3 = -2 and P_in(3)-3 = 0.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, my mistake with the -4. So this is indeed the way to do it. Did this work for you?

Comment: ya. Well, here's the problem: P_in2 = P_in -3. So ismembertol(P_in2,P_in-3,eps) gives all indices of P_in. It does work. But what I want is the following: Let P_in(5) = 5 and P_out(5) = 10. Now P_in2(5) = P_in(5)-3 = 2. What is P_out2(5) ? I'm sorry, this confuses me so much

Comment: The answer works for the question as you posted it. If you understand now your question is slightly different, then you can edit your question. If it is more than slightly different then you should ask a new question. Sounds to me like you have some confusion between indices and values. Try to make this clearer for yourself and then edit the question or ask a new one.