# How to use ismember-command properly

Tags: matlab

And again I have troubles with finding corresponding values:

Consider a vector P_in and a vector spacing_Pin: 
spacing_Pin is a vector starting at -27 and ending at 2. The spacing is 0.0001. 
The first entries of spacing_Pin are:

- -27
- -26.9999
- -26.9998
- ...
- -26.7400  (2601th entry)

The first entry of P_in is -26.7400, which is clearly included in both P_in and in spacing_Pin. However, when I type `ismember(P_in,spacing_Pin)` in Matlab, the result is a vector starting with:

- 0
- 0
- 1

So, it says the first entry of P_in is not included in spacing_Pin. But that's wrong!

Here's a small version of my code:

```
P_in1           = table(:,1)
P_out1          = table(:,2)
spacing_Pin     = transpose(linspace(-27,2,290001)); % spacing = 0.0001
P_out1_intrp    = interp1(P_in1,P_out1,spacing_Pin,'spline');

P_in = P_in1 + some_constant; 

% max(some_constant) = 0.0205, min(some_constant) = -1.135
% the entries of some_constant have many digits after the dot. 
% The first entry for example is: -0,117094826063334
% this might be the issue since my spacing has accurracy 0.0001
% this is probably not the problem with ismember(), but another one I have to solve

P_out = P_out1_intrp(ismember(P_in,spacing_Pin));
```

Ok. If you need to have the values of some_constant or some other variable, I can try to upload it somehow. I don't know how at the moment, since all tables are pretty long.

Comment: Hello again! Please post your code. It is impossible to help you without understanding exactly what you are running. Also, read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a minimal complete example.

Comment: ok. I just edited my question. I hope my writing is not too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609994/how-to-use-find-in-matlab-in-order-to-find-decimals), using [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) is preferable.

```
freq = -27:0.01:2;
P_in = [-26.74, pi, 0, 42];
P_in_isInFreq = ismembertol(P_in, freq, eps);
```

Here, `P_in_isInFreq` will be `[1 0 1 0]`. Note how the output is a logical array the same size as the first input.

Comment: ok, thx for oyur help Naveh! I have changed the last line of my example code to `P_out = P_out1_intrp(ismembertol(P_in,spacing_Pin,0.01));` . Now `ismembertol(P_in,spacing_Pin,0.01)`has a 1 in every entry. P_in has 40 entries. The changed code line now returns the first 40 entries of P_out1_intrp. This is not what I want, however. I mean, for example: -17.77 is the 10th entry of P_in. It is also included in spacing_Pin (entry 92301). Therefore my P_out should have an entry `P_out1_intrp(92301)` = 45.9905. But there is no such value in my P_out!